# Which is the efficient way to insert huge records in DB .. Batch insert or Conection Pool usin Akka Actors

Tags: akka, connection-pooling, actor, slick, batch-insert

I m reading huge file and inserting records in to MySql Table using slick and akka actor. My approach is-

1. Multiple actors to read file and Single db actor to insert record into table. Here I use batch insert of slick. (implicit session)
2. Can I use connection pool fpr this with multiple db actors to insert records in  table. Each actor will insert one record.(no batch insert)

So what is the efficient way to do this..??

Thanks..

Comment: How about many actors all doing match inserts?

Comment: If your loading files, the best way would be to move the file to the database server host and do parallel load on it to avoid the network traffic.  If that's not possible, you need to do batch inserts, otherwise you getting crushed with small log writes on the server. I can't help you with regards to the akka framework though.  Not sure if you can do non-logged inserts with mySql, but that would also help your performance.  It really depends on your failure tolerance level and how much you want to spend (ex. wider disk stripes, more memory, etc.)  Single inserts will kill you though.

Comment: cross posted here: https://groups.google.com/d/msgid/scalaquery/b1389b2b-cea6-4c32-8450-0779c204785f%40googlegroups.com?utm_medium=email&utm_source=footer

Answer (score 1):

With a single DB actor you might have a bottleneck on your hand since an actor can process only one message at a time. I'd go with routers (SmallestMailbox/Balancing) with a pool of actors (separating writes and reads). Each actor would obtain a connection though a pool to avoid resource wastage and do inserts (or batch idk, depends on perf) from there.

You should also be wary about JDBC. To my knowledge there's no mature async JDBC driver right now, so you should handle things accordingly. What is commonly done in this case to avoid blocking actors is to isolate the blocking ones in their own thread pool using a [PinnedDispatcher](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/snapshot/scala/dispatchers.html#Types_of_dispatchers). Keep in mind that this doesn't scale that much so don't go overboard with it.

Comment: Is there really nothing in Slick taking care of connection pooling?

Comment: @matt Slick is just a data access library, connection pooling isn't its job. That being said, you can easily plug in a pooled datasource in it.

Comment: Well I guess easily is relative although true